# Find files that do not have search term

Tags: bash

I am looking for a fast way to search through thousands of log files to find the ones with an error. Unfortunately for me, only the ones that completed successfully are marked with the "Job Completed" term while the ones that crashed will not contain this line.

I stored the exact names of these jobs as the filename. And while it is useful to do the following:

```
grep "Job Completed" * > completeJobs.txt
```

in my log directory, I really wish to know the filenames of the jobs that do not contain this line.

Is there a complement to the grep command above to solve my issue?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: suggest that you read the man pages for commands before you ask for help - it's really the best method

Comment: What I may not have made clear is that these log files have lines that say things other than "Jobs Completed." If I were to just the -vl command, I will still grab files with "Job Completed" lines as well as other lines of text. Instead. I have done the following for a complete solution:
`grep -l "Job Completed" * > ../temp1`
`grep -vl "Job Completed" * > ../temp2`
`cat temp1 temp2 | sort | uniq -u > jobsNotCompleted`

And, I understand the second grep function could very well be replaced with an ls command, but for a more clear solution, I've written it as such.

Comment: @user1575175 Can you post this as an answer to your own q, and mark it as correct? It is a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You want option `-L`:

> Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
>                 file from which no output would normally have been printed.

```
grep -L 'Job Completed' * >../jobsNotCompleted
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the -v switch to reverse the grep search.

```
 grep -v "Job Completed" * > incompleteJobs.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply try

```
grep -vl 'Job Completed' * > notCompletedJobs.txt
```

or

```
grep -v 'Job Completed' * > notCompletedJobs.txt
```

Depending of your needs

### Note

From `man grep` :

> ```
>     -v, --invert-match
> ```
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
>
> ```
>    -l, --files-with-matches
> ```
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified  by POSIX.)

Answer (score -1):

Checking the `man` page, you can invert the match with -v option

```
grep -v "Job Completed" * > uncompletedJobs.txt
```